# TreeView display hierarchical data

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have the following two model-classes:

```
public class FileItem : NotifyBase
{
    public FileItem(string fullPath)
    {
        FullPath = fullPath;
    }

    public string FullPath
    {
        get { return Get<string>(); }
        set
        {
            Set(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            OnPropertyChanged("Directory");
        }
    }

    public string Directory
    {
        get { return Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath); }
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return Path.GetFileName(FullPath); }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Directory : NotifyBase
{
    public Directory(string fullPath)
    {
        FullPath = fullPath;
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
        Directories = new ObservableCollection<Directory>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
    {
        get { return Get<ObservableCollection<FileItem>>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Directory> Directories
    {
        get { return Get<ObservableCollection<Directory>>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }

    public string FullPath
    {
        get { return Get<string>(); }
        set
        {
            Set(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("DirectoryName");
        }
    }

    public string DirectoryName
    {
        get
        {
            string[] directoryNameSplit = FullPath.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (directoryNameSplit.Length > 0)
            {
                return directoryNameSplit[directoryNameSplit.Length - 1];
            }
            return "UNKNOWN";
        }
    }
}
```

The class `NotifyBase` is just an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I load the data from the filesystem and so I have a hierarchy of objects. Now I want to display that hierarchy of `Directory`s and `FileItem`s in the View as a `TreeView`.

In the ViewModel I have an `ObservableCollection<Directory>` called Directories with the root nodes.

My View is:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" x:Name="tv"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Directories, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Directory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Directories}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=DirectoryName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:FileItem}">
            <Label Content="{Binding FileName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

All folders are displayed perfect, but I don't see any `FileItem`s and I don't know why. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have your two collections separate, and you are not binding to `Files` anywhere.

Instead of two collections, have one collection of two types.

Comment: I need this structure to represent the deep hierarchy of directories. Or how would you solve this?